# How to parse two different type of string formats to a date?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am trying to format a date like these

august 2011, and august 24,2011

I am using this to parse them now..

```
//set the pattern here to look like the pattern you are expecting in your 'Date' variable
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");

 //Get the release date
                     releaseDate = postIt.next().text();

                     Date realDate = null;
                    try {
                        realDate = sdf.parse(releaseDate);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 

                     int i = 0;
                    String gameDate =  realDate.toString();
```

i get the following error in my debug.

```
08-26 22:02:44.571: WARN/System.err(29218): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "August 2011" (at offset 11)
08-26 22:02:44.571: WARN/System.err(29218):     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
```

How would i go about making this to where it will read both formats?

EDIT:

This is how it parses it now...

```
08-27 00:10:48.951: VERBOSE/Dates(30449): August 2011
```

If formated the August 2011 
to

```
08-27 00:10:48.951: ERROR/FormattedDATE(30449): Mon Aug 01 00:00:00 EDT 2011
```

They all parse to this same date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need a format string for each e.g.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatDriver {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

        SimpleDateFormat dayMonthYearFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat monthYearFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");                

        //String date1 = "August 11,2005";
        String date1 = "August 2005";
        Date realDate = null;

        try {
            realDate = dayMonthYearFormatter.parse(date1);
            System.out.println("parsed date -> " + realDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {                    
            // fall back on other formatter
            try {               
                realDate = monthYearFormatter.parse(date1);
                System.out.println("parsed date -> " + realDate);
            } catch(ParseException e2) {
                System.err.println("could not parse" + date1);              
            }
        }                          
    }        
}
```

I would recommend you check out http://joda-time.sourceforge.net

This is just an idea, not sure if I'd really use it but a tokenizer could be used to see what date type it is, 2 tokens for 'August 11, 2005', 1 for 'August 2005'. So use one formatter if token count is 1, other formatter if token count is 2 e.g.

```
    int tokenCount = 0;
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("August 11, 2005", ",");
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tokenizer.nextToken();
        tokenCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("token count -> " + tokenCount);
```

Comment: How would i know if its August 21, 2011, or just August 2011? Based on a list?

Comment: Also what are you suggesting from the Joda-Time?

Comment: depends, where do you get those strings from 'August 21, 2011' and 'August 2011'?

Comment: It should save you time parsing dates, quoting this article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jodatime/index.html - "an easy-to-use open source date/time library for the Java™ platform. As you'll see in this article, Joda-Time eases the pain and tedium of manipulating dates and time"

Comment: Im getting them from a HTML page that is returned to a list with each date one by one... if the date is August 21,2011 format, it parses. if its August 2011 it doesnt.

Comment: if there are only the 2 formats you mentioned you could use a tokenizer to see if you dealing with 2 tokens (Aug 2010) or more (Aug 21, 2010) and then use either format string in your SimpleDateFormat, either "MMMM dd,yyyy" or "MMMM yyyy"

Comment: Could you put an example in your answer?

Comment: @yoshi24 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2912/discussion-between-eon-and-yoshi24)

Comment: Okay i was in the chat. You never came

Comment: sorry was there but couldn't figure out how to enter a message :( will update my original post with code, just testing it now

Comment: Is it better to do it the first way you suggested?

Comment: I would go for the first way, if you only have 2 date formats use one formatter, if that fails use the other one in catch block as above. But you need to be sure you are only dealing with 2 date formats (with and without the date)

Comment: I tried the method above. its only giving the print line statement couldnt parse August 2011

Comment: did you take the whole code? which jdk are you using? i tested this on java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.2) (6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: updated my post changed format string from "MMMM dd, yyyy" to "MMMM dd,yyyy", can you check my code again?

Comment: I dont see what you changed"?

Comment: changed a few lines in the main method, take the whole DateFormatDriver and try it, you can test 2 date formats by uncommenting out one of the date1 lines, checked it here, it worked for me

Comment: I just tried your exact code.. it parsed the date to   parsed date -> Mon Aug 01 00:00:00 EDT 2005

Comment: Maybe i should format it to "mm-yyyy" for August 2011, and mm-dd-yyyy for the other?

Comment: Its Force closing when it catches the parse exception